# Wordpress Installation Database Error -1

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a fresh new install of Wordpress on my DO droplet but it's returning an error that I can't find anything similar on the internet. :(

The steps I did were:

1. downloaded from wordpress.org, edited wp-config and uploaded to my
   server
2. created a new user with "all privileges" and access to the newly
   created database
3. Ran my URL to complete the 5min install, that asked me some infos
   about user, password email.

After the last step I received tons of the following error:

```
WordPress database error: [Got error -1 from storage engine]
INSERT INTO wp_options (option_name, option_value, autoload) VALUES 
('siteurl', 'http://fazendohidromel.com.br', 'yes'),
('home', 'http://fazendohidromel.com.br', 'yes'),
('blogname', 'Meu site', 'yes'),
('blogdescription', 'Só mais um site WordPress', 'yes'),
('users_can_register', '0', 'yes'),
('admin_email', 'you@example.com', 'yes'),
```

The same error above repeats to a lot of tables, not sure if it happens to EVERY SINGLE TABLE. But curious thing is that the tables are created and I have the wordpress structure on my database, but no content in the ones I looked at.

Any ideas of whats going on?

Comment: it seems sth to do with storage engine, what is your DB settings and configuration?

Comment: It was exactly that. innodb_force_recovery was on because of a previous problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's always like that, I research hours before I post here, and after I post I find my problem in 10min!

Anyways, my problem was that I had the ***innodb_force_recovery*** turned on on my mysql mycnf configs, because of a previous problem. Turned it off and worked like a charm.